# Covariance of the product of a random scalar and a random vector

Tags: probability, random-variables

What is the covariance matrix of the product of a random scalar and a random vector in general (if any) and in all special cases, in terms of the variance of the scalar and the covariance matrix of the vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Label the scalar $v_1$ and the vector $v = (v_2, \dots, v_{n+1})$ (assuming the vector has $n$ components). Then your covariance matrix between the scalar and the vector is just the covariance matrix of $n+1$ scalars. It would look like this : 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbb{C}\mathrm{ov}[v_1,v_1] & \mathbb{C}\mathrm{ov}[v_1,v_2] & \dots & \mathbb{C}\mathrm{ov}[v_1,v_{n+1}] \\
\mathbb{C}\mathrm{ov}[v_2,v_1] & \mathbb{C}\mathrm{ov}[v_2,v_2] & \dots & \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \\
\mathbb{C}\mathrm{ov}[v_{n+1},v_1] & & & \mathbb{C}\mathrm{ov}[v_{n+1},v_{n+1}]
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The $n \times n$ submatrix in the lower right corner would be the covariance matrix of $v$ and $\mathrm{\mathbb Cov}[v_1,v_1]$ would be on the top left corner. The only new information this matrix has is the relationships between $v_1$ and the components of $v$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Am I right to think that there is no way to exclude the relationships between $v_1$ and the components of $v$? (Except, of course, when their covariance are actually zero in our data) I.e to have $cov(v_1)$ and $cov(v)$ separate? I.e, can we write $cov(v_1 v)$ in terms of $cov(v_1)$ and $cov(v)$?

Comment: Suppose $n = 1$ and you just have two scalars $v_1$ and $v_2$. There is no way to compute the covariance of $v_1$ and $v_2$ given their variances... because it's impossible to know how they vary with respect to each other only by knowing their variance. For instance, two Gaussians $v_1$ and $v_2$ could have variance $1$ and be totally correlated or not at all, or anything in between. You need the extra $n$ matrix entries (remember the covariance matrix is symmetric, so you don't actually "need" $2n$ entries, just $n$) to understand the covariance matrix of $v_1$ and $v$.