# Covariance of a random variable and a vector

Tags: statistics

How do I compute the covariance of:

$\left [X, \begin{pmatrix}2X\\X-Y \end{pmatrix}\right]$

with $X$ and $Y$  independent RV's?

[image]

[Covariance of the product of a random scalar and a random vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508659/covariance-of-the-product-of-a-random-scalar-and-a-random-vector)

Comment: What does $2X \choose X-Y$ mean for arbitrary $X,Y$?

Comment: Also, are $X,Y$ supposed to be positive integers?

Comment: No, I should have added that $X$~$N(5,2)$ and $Y$~$Bin(10,0.5)$, $X,Y$ independent random variables

Comment: So X is Gaussian? Are you using the generalized binomial coefficient formula then?

Comment: X is gaussian. I don't understand your second question. $Y$ is distributed binomially with mean=0.5 and 10 trials.

Comment: So how do u define $2X \choose X-Y$?

Comment: I've amended my post to include the page from my lecture notes. Is it any clearer?

Comment: Sorry..but I'm not sure I get the parentheses .. It's normally defined only for integer top and bottom (there is a generalized version tho...)

Comment: Here's what I'm talking about....still don't know what $2X \choose X-Y$ means.  http://planetmath.org/generalizedbinomialcoefficients

Comment: $ \begin{pmatrix}2X\\X-Y \end{pmatrix}$ is a vector, not a binomial coefficient

Comment: Sorry..totally missed your title.i see that $X$ and the vector are not in the same space so I don't know how to interpret the covariance of a scalar and a vector...seems odd.